# Sound when counter reaches specific time? Android

Tags: java, android

first of all pardon my English, but I think it's understandable.
So in this app is a counter and I need it to do sound when it reaches for example 30 seconds. 
note: this is my first question here so if I broke any rules or I could have asked better way, let me know please

---

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mStartButton;
    private Button mPauseButton;
    private Button mResetButton;
    private Chronometer mChronometer;

    private long lastPause;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        mPauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        mResetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
        mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (lastPause != 0){
                    mChronometer.setBase(mChronometer.getBase() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastPause);
                }
                else{
                    mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                }

                mChronometer.start();
                mStartButton.setEnabled(false);
                mPauseButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lastPause = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                mChronometer.stop();
                mPauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                mStartButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        mResetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mChronometer.stop();
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                lastPause = 0;
                mStartButton.setEnabled(true);
                mPauseButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you dont need a chronometer but a handler instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define global integer variable as counter and count it in `Chronometer`'s `OnChronometerTickListener`, and when it reach for example 30 then play sound and reset your counter:

```
int c = -1; // define global

chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
        c++;
        if(c == 30) {
            c = 0;
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ding);
            mp.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that will help!